# how to optimize x264 for online live education scene？

Tags: video-streaming, video-processing, codec, x264, video-codecs

I am working on a x264 optimization project for online live education. Often, the teachers are sitting before the camera, and doesn't have big motion, and the background are the same (exception light changes). And is there some papers that I can refer to that can reduce the bit rate or improve the video quality?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for region of interest (ROI) encoding. Here is one paper: https://www.thinkmind.org/download.php?articleid=mmedia_2013_6_10_40068

Here is an encoder on top of x264:

https://github.com/ChaoticEnigma/h264-roi

For the talking head (speaker) you want to allocate more bits than for the background.

The problem becomes more interesting if you want to track the face in the frame and dynamically change the region of interest.
It is an interesting problem - good luck.